# Point my machine's IP address to a different Apache virtual host?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I am running a local Apache development server on my Windows 8.1 machine. Say I have two virtual hosts setup on my local Apache server:

`http://localhost/` points to `C:\htdocs\localhost\`

`http://otherdomain/` points to `C:\htdocs\myTestWebsite\`

When a remote user enters my IP address into their browser, the browser returns the contents of `localhost`, of course.

Is it possible to configure something on my computer to return the contents of `otherdomain` when someone browses my IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out at last!

I changed the `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory>` directives in `httpd.conf` to `C:\htdocs\myTestWebsite` and gave the corresponding virtual host, `otherdomain`, in `httpd-vhosts.conf` my IP address, i.e., `<VirtualHost 10.0.0.5:80>`.

Works!